# Selenium web driver launching web pages in sequence

Tags: java, selenium

How do we launch links one after another in selenium. I am clicking one icon the it launches new page after 30 seconds the page disappears then I need to launch another icon in the home page. How do I do that in selenium web driver?

Here is my xpath:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/span[2]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/span[2]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/span[2]")).click();
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to achieve. The command with `implicitWait` is to set the driver timeout. It means that if the driver tries to locate an element, it will wait any response to the stipulated time. I think this is not what you want. Do you want to open links in parallel? Do you want to open / do something / close? Please, improve your question with more description about what exactly you want as the result for the test (edit the question please - don't say everything in comments).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your post is that you want to click on an icon, which opens up a new window, new window closes after 30 odd seconds and then you need to click on the next icon to open a fresh new window. If this is the case then read on.

Not sure you are using implicit wait correctly. You do not have to repeat the command if duration is not changed. It is set for the lifetime of the driver. Also if the links are not visible use an explicit wait on the clickability of the link. If you are trying to use implicit wait as a timer then you are not doing it correctly. It will wait only till the element is not found and error out after the time interval is over.

Use a custom explicit wait to wait for the new opened window to close instead.

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 1;
    }
});
```